# What can cause .NET assembly registration to fail?

Tags: .net, windows, windows-installer

We've seen an issue where one of our installers (msi) returns the error code 2908, which is used to indicate that an assembly failed to register.  Later in the installation, we get the following (sanitized) error:

> MyAssemblyName, version="1.0.1.1",
>   culture="neutral",
>   publicKeyToken="119EFC79848A50".
>   Please refer to Help and Support for
>   more information. HRESULT: 0x8002802F.

The assembly registers properly on most systems.  Has anyone else encountered this issue?  How did you solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a pair of [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/astebner/archive/2004/11/10/255346.aspx) [postings](http://blogs.msdn.com/astebner/archive/2007/06/12/3260076.aspx) that appear to cover this topic.